# How can i sum of counts in my query ? Sql server query attached

Tags: sql-server, group-by, count, sum

I want to use Sum on Count that I am already using in my query my query is,

```
select R.region_id as Id,R.region_name as Name, count(IR.Id) as AgencyreportCount,count(AR.Id) as IndividualreportCount 
     from region R 
left join governorate G
           on r.region_id=g.region_id
left join IndividualReports IR
            on g.governorate_id=IR.governorate_id
left join AgencyReports AR
            on g.governorate_id=AR.governorate_id
left join AgencyUsers AU
            on IR.AgencyUserId=AU.Id
left join Agencies A
            on AU.AgencyId=A.Id where A.Id=1
Group by R.region_id,R.region_name
```

I want to add sum total using these counts in my query `sum(count(IR.Id)+count(AR.Id)) as Total`

Comment: The way you wrote the query, unless you have missing reports in your joins (and generate nulls), your counts will give the same numbers. Also the numbers will be even more inflated by the other joins (AgencyUsers / Agency). Is this intended? or do you want to know how many individual reports you have and how many agency reports and the total sum ?

Comment: @DumitrescuBogdan you are right it is giving same sum or zero unable to understand what join error I am doing

Comment: @DumitrescuBogdan can you rewrite this query in order to remove errors your help will be appreciated ?

Comment: Done .. in answer ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say something like this:

```
select 
    R.region_id as Id
    ,R.region_name as Name
    ,IndividualReports.IndividualreportCount
    ,AgencyReports.AgencyreportCount
    ,isnull(IndividualReports.IndividualreportCount,0) + isnull(AgencyReports.AgencyreportCount,0) as TotalCountPerRegion
from region R 
outer apply (
    select count(*)
    from governorate G
    join IndividualReports IR
        on g.governorate_id=IR.governorate_id
    where r.region_id=g.region_id
) IndividualReports(IndividualreportCount)
outer apply (
select count(*)
    from governorate G
    join AgencyReports AR
        on g.governorate_id=AR.governorate_id
    where r.region_id=g.region_id
) AgencyReports(AgencyreportCount)
group by 
    R.region_id
    ,R.region_name
```

If you want the total sum just take out everything except the sum and wrap with with the SUM().

Comment: it is giving me error on this line "R.region_id as Id" second last line incorrect syntax new key word as

Comment: Sorry, copy paste .. I left the "as" in the group by

Comment: I am also using AgencyId = 1 like A.Id=1
 how to adjust in my query

Comment: To Query based on Agency, from what I understand in your schema, you need to change the outer apply of the individual reports into a cross apply. And continue the join (should not be left join) to AgencyUsers and AgencyReports as you had in your initial query.

Answer (score 3):

I believe you don't need the the `SUM` operator, just add both`COUNT` together.

```
count(IR.Id) + count(AR.Id) as Total
```

Unless you want the total sum of counts *independent* of regions, which would use a windowed `SUM`.

```
SUM(count(IR.Id) + count(AR.Id)) OVER () as Total
```